# Why does x++ and ++x exist, and x += 2 but not x =+ 2?

Tags: c++, operators

In C++ (and in other programming languages), `(x++)` evaluates x as token, then increments x by 1, while `(++x)` first increments x then evaluates the new value of x as token.

Similarly, `(x += 2)` exists (evaluates x as token, then increments x by 2). However, `(x =+ 2)` does not boil down to incrementing x by 2 then evaluating the new value of x as token, but rather is evaluated as `x = +2`.

In order to distinguish `x =+ 2` and `x = +2`, proper spacing would be necessary, but I don't see why that would be a problem.

Why is `(x =+ 2)` not designed to perform the function of two pre-increments?

Edit: The purpose of this is not to look pretty, but to facilitate some cases that may come up in loops.

Comment: because proper spacing IS necessary, e.g. `x=+2` is what. `x = x + 2`? or `x = positive 2`? and once you have to enter proper spacing, having `x =+ 2` and `x += 2` saves you no time/space at all.

Comment: The purpose of this is not looking pretty, but to facilitate some cases of loops.

Comment: and remember that C's buzzphrase is "all the power of assembler with all the legibility of assembler". Most cpus have an `inc` instruction to do a simple `x = x + 1`, whereas few/none will have an `inc2`. so while x++ can map directly to that `inc` instruction, there is no mapping for a +2 variant, so you might as well just write out the +2 increment in full.

Comment: Could you show a concrete example of where that syntax would be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is `(x =+ 2)` not designed to perform the function of two `(++x)` expressions?

Because whitespace in C++ isn't significant (modulo separating keywords like `class`). It would be a very sharp break in the language if these two statements meant widely different things:

```
x =+ 2;
x = +2;
```

Let's not turn C++ into Python.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote for the Python jab, but I won't. Whitespace doesn't work this way in Python. Indentation is significant in Python, otherwise whitespace is no more significant than it is in C++.

Answer (score 2):

I recall the K&R book (at least the first edition, and I don't have mine handy right now) saying that `=+` was originally intended to be the operator in C, but it was ambiguous to parse. So `+=` was chosen. Requiring whitespace to disambiguate isn't terribly friendly in a language where whitespace is usually not significant.

Answer (score 2):

This is because people could easily interpret x=+2 as x= positive 2.